# Unbind click in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question. How I can unbind the click of element in react?
I have button, when I click on it, it increases score + 1, and after this click I want to remove it. How I can do this?

Help me please!

```html
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      result: 2,
      score: 0
    };
    
    this.getRes = this.getRes.bind(this);
  }
  

 
  
  getRes() {
    if (this.state.result == 2) {
      this.setState({score: this.state.score+1})
      
      this.getRes.unbind(this);
      
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div style={{paddingTop: 10}}>
        <p>
        <button>1</button>
        <button onClick={this.getRes}>{this.state.result}</button>
        </p>
        
          <p>
        <button>1</button>
        <button onClick={this.getRes}>{this.state.result}</button>
        </p>
        
        
        <p>{this.state.score}</p>
        
        </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Toggle />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: don't unbind the event, just use state and logic to see if you have incremented yet, and if you already have, just make the function noop

Comment: when would `this.state.score == this.state.score` be `false` ?

Comment: If you don't want a click-handler on an element, then don't add a click-handler to that element. In React you do not mutate/change the DOM. You tell react how the *(new)* DOM should look like *(either with or without click-handler)* and let react take the necessary steps to get there.

Answer (score 4):

In React, you change your UI by making `render()` describe the new state, not by manually binding or unbinding or changing things.

Change your `render()` method to only pass `this.getRes` to `onClick` if you want the handler to by bound:

```
onClick={... ? this.getRes : null}
```

Comment: what to put instead 3 dots?

Comment: @rapprogtrainsite: Whatever condition you want.